Null Id Generated for Entity with Embedded Id in Spring Boot 3.2.4 (Hibernate 6.4.4)
I'm facing a peculiar issue with saving entities using embedded IDs in Spring Boot 3.2.4 (which includes Hibernate 6.4.4). This problem doesn't occur with Spring Boot 3.1.1 (presumably with Hibernate 6.2.x).
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Null id generated for entity ABC  [...] Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Null id generated for entity ABC [...] 
Key Observation:
The error seems to be triggered specifically by the newer Hibernate version (6.4.4). Downgrading to 6.2.5 successfully avoids the issue.
Potential Cause:
My code utilizes the @PrePersist annotation on the entity class. I can confirm that this annotation isn't being invoked when using Hibernate 6.4.4. In contrast, it functions as expected with Hibernate 6.2.5 (or when using Spring Boot 3.1.1). This could potentially be related to internal Hibernate logic changes in the newer version.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have suggestions for troubleshooting this behavior?
Thank you in advance!
If you want to replicate this example, create a new entity that has a composite primary key. You will also need to create a new entity that references this composite primary key entity.
@Entity
public class LocalizedText {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CompositeKey contentId; 
    @OneToMany()
    private LocalizedContent localizedContent; 

    @Embeddable
    public static class CompositeKey implements Serializable {
        private String id; 
        private Char language; 
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void preBeforePersist() {
        if (contentId == null) {
            contentId = new CompositeKey(localizedContent.getId(), language);
        }
    }
}

Dependency used:
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>6.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

I've thoroughly searched existing issues but haven't found a direct match.
Upgrading JPA and Hibernate Core to the latest versions doesn't resolve the error.
Cleaning and rebuilding the project also proves ineffective.
